# Magento2 change the cart icon

Tags: magento2

I was wondering if there was a simple way to change the default cart icon? I have been looking through the documentation and haven't been able to find a clear answer.

Answer (score 4):

Magento 2 use font icon. `.minicart-wrapper .action.showcart:before` selector responsible for cart icon.
See [minicart.less](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/design/frontend/Magento/blank/Magento_Checkout/web/css/source/module/_minicart.less#L106) for details

Answer (score 1):

As per KAndy's answer you can use `.minicart-wrapper .action.showcart:before` selector to change the icon, for example I wanted to change it with [Google Material's Shopping Basket](https://design.google.com/icons/#ic_shopping_basket) icon so I added following in my _theme.less file

```
  .minicart-wrapper {
margin-right: 10px;

.action.showcart::before, .action.showcart.active::before {
  display: inline-block;
 white-space: nowrap;
word-wrap: normal;
direction: ltr;
content: '\e8cb';
color: @color-white;
-moz-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: other than including the above code in less file, is there anything else needs to be included, because i'm getting plain sqaure when I use your code

Comment: You'll need to add external css library first of course. e.g. in default_head_blocks.xml add <head>
        <css src="http://myexternalcssfile.css" src_type="url"/>
    </head>

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding this answer if someone have own icon image and plan to use it. This method will be helpful. Helped me in theme based on blank theme.

```
.minicart-wrapper .action.showcart:before {
         content: url(http://your-domain.com/.../cart-image.png);

}
```